# Getting wierd Uncaught TypeError: this._saveFile is not a function with es6

Tags: javascript, function, subclass, es6-class

I am getting a strange error in es6. The "this" value is not what it is

supposed to be and it prevents me from calling this._saveFile() in the

code below.

```
    /**
     * Performs the actions for saving the file.
     * @param  {[type]} data [description]
     * @return {[type]}      [description]
     */
  _saveFile(data){

      var p = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        if(!isStream.readable(data.stream)){
          reject("Data object must have a stream property that is a readable stream");
        }
        else if(typeof data.fileName !== 'string'){
          reject("The fileName property is missing or malformed in the data object");
        }
        else{
          let pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
          pool.getConnection((err,conn) => {
            if(err){

              reject(err);
            }

            let m = new HackFileMapper(conn);
            let dc = new DataConverter();
            dc.streamToBase64(data.stream)
            .then(base64Data => {
              m.saveFile({
                fileName:data.fileName,
                fileData:base64Data
              },{
                sharerId:data.fields.sharerId,
                shareeId:data.fields.shareeId
              })
              .then(fileId => {
                conn.release();
                resolve(fileId);
              });
            }).catch(reason => {
              conn.release();
              reject(reason);
            });
          });

        }

      });
      return p;
    };




  /**
   * Tries to handle the request as a save file request.
   * If it can't then it passes the request to the
   * next one in the chain.
   *
   * @param  {[type]} request  [description]
   * @param  {[type]} response [description]
   * @return {boolean}  True if the request was handled successfully,
   *  either by this handler or a handler further along the chain.
   */
  handle(request, response){

    var self = this;

    var p = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

      if(typeof request === 'undefined' || request === null){

          reject("The handle function must be passed a valid Request and Response object.");
      }
      else{ // try and process it.

        var contentType = request.headers['content-type'];
        if(contentType !== null &&
          typeof contentType !== 'undefined' &&
          contentType.indexOf('multipart/form-data') === 0){ // can it do it?

            // handle it here.
            parseFormdata(request,(err,data) => {

              if(err){
                SaveFileHandler._send400Response(response,"an error occurred parsing the forma data");
              }
              else if(data.parts.length < 1){
                SaveFileHandler._send400Response(response,"No files sent");
              }
              else if(!data.fields.supplierId || !data.fields.customerId){
                SaveFileHandler._send400Response(response,"supplerId and customerId must be included.");

              }else{
                this._saveFile(data).then(fileId => {
                  ConnectionPool.getInstance().getConnection((err,conn) => {
                    var m = new HackFileMapper(conn);
                    m.loadIcon(fileId).
                    then(icon => {

                      response.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
                      response.statusCode = 200;
                      response.end(JSON.stringify(icon));
                      resolve(true);

                    });
                  });

                }).
                catch(reason => {
                  SaveFileHandler._send400Response(response,reason);
                });
              }
            });
        }
        else{ // pass it on.

            self.successor.handle(request,response)
            .then(result => resolve(result))
            .catch(reason => reject(reason)); // for testing purposes.
        }

      } // else

    });
    return p;
  }; // end fn.
```

When I run this using npm test I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this._saveFile is not a function
      at parseFormdata (src/request_handlers/SaveFileHandler.js:114:22)
      at exports.Dispenser.internals.Dispenser.<anonymous> (node_modules/parse-formdata/index.js:43:20)
```

I tried putting "this" in front of the function as well as storing a

reference to "this" as "self" and the same problems occurs.

console.log(self) prints out information that is totally unrelated to this

class. It is not a asynchronous issue, it must be something else.

Comment: use ```this._helperFunction``` not ```_helperFunction```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `handle`, your arrow functions are all properly inheriting the `this` from the outer block, which means that if `this._saveFile` isn't being referenced correctly in the nested blocks, `this` doesn't refer to the instantiated object at the top level of `handle`. This sort of thing can happen when you pass a function as a callback without explicitly `bind`ing it to the expected calling context, for example:

```
var server = new HttpServer(handler.handle);
```

Here, you're passing the `handle` function to the constructor, but *without the calling context of `handler`*, which means that when `HttpServer` calls the callback, its `this` no longer references `handler`.

```js
const handler = {
  handlerProp: 'handlerProp',
  handle() {
    console.log(this.handlerProp);
  }
};
function invoker(callback) {
  callback();
}

// Works:
handler.handle();

// Doesn't work:
invoker(handler.handle);
```

One option is to use `.bind` to ensure that when the callback is called, the calling context is as expected:

```
var server = new HttpServer(handler.handle.bind(handler));
```

Another option is to pass a function that *invokes* `handler.handle` by itself, with the proper calling context:

```
var server = new HttpServer(() => handler.handle());
```

```js
const handler = {
  handlerProp: 'handlerProp',
  handle() {
    console.log(this.handlerProp);
  }
};
function invoker(callback) {
  callback();
}

// Fixed:
invoker(handler.handle.bind(handler));

// or:
invoker(() => handler.handle());
```

Comment: Thank you, that works in this small example.  But in my projects code that does not work. (but the issue is the same).   The _helperFunction() is called within a asyncronous block.  So I made a reference to this by doing var self = this, then calling self._helperFunction().  Then I get Uncaught TypeError: self._helperFunction  is not a function.   I'll try to reproduce the problem in a smaller piece of code.  (I have to rephrase the question)

Comment: `self = this` is an antipattern in modern JS - use arrow functions instead, if at all possible

Comment: @kiwicomb123 you should be clear on what you ask and what you need

Comment: I made a mistake and oversimplified the code.  The code is now updated.

Comment: @kiwicomb123 From the code you just edited in, it looks to be the same problem: you're trying to call `_helperFunction`, but `_helperFunction` is a not a standalone function, it's a property on the instantiated object itself. Change `_helperFunction().then` to `this._helperFunction().then`

Comment: Indeed it does seem to be the same problem. However is my actual program saying this._helperFunction(). then   does not work and I get the same error.  Are you okay with me pasting a long piece of code?

Comment: @kiwicomb123 Sure, even if it's long, it sounds like it's down to a pretty simple issue of getting the proper `this` reference, feel free to edit it into your question

Comment: Your probably right, but aside from storing a reference to "this" using "self" I am not sure how to do it.  I didn't know self = this was an anti-pattern.  (Been using it a lot with KnockoutJS)

Comment: @kiwicomb123 Thanks. Your arrow functions all look fine, each block should be properly inheriting `this` from the outer block, up until the top of the `handle` function - which makes me think that `this` (or `self`) isn't actually referencing the instantiated object at that top level. For example, on the first line of `handle`, try `console.log(this.handle)`, which you're expecting to reference the current function, but it probably doesn't. This can happen if `handle` is not nvoked with the proper calling context, eg `const handle = obj.handle; handle();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178066/discussion-between-certainperformance-and-kiwicomb123).